# My query is not working at all and throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use fluent API to Include another table but want to reference some keys from parent to parent table but that is throwing some error when i reload page.

here is my query.

```
var allocations = _context.TblCourseAllocations
                
                .Include(ca => ca.Department)
                .Include(ca => ca.Department.TblCourses)
                .Include(ca => ca.Department.TblPrograms)
                .Include(ca => ca.Department.TblSemesters.Where(s => s.ProgramCode.Equals(ca.ProgramCode)))
                .Where(ca => ca.EmployeeCode.Equals(employee.EmployeeCode) 
                             & ca.SemesterName.Equals(semester) 
                             & ca.PaymentStatus.Equals("Regular/Unpaid")
                )
                .AsSplitQuery()
               .AsEnumerable().OrderBy(d => d.ProgramSession).GroupBy(ca => ca.CourseCode).ToList();
```

On tblSemesters my condition is not working but there i want to implement multiple conditions. Any help or opinion will be highly appreciated.

The error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(t3 => EF.Property(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType:
> TblDepartment ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
> Inner IsNullable: True , "DepartmentCode") != null && object.Equals(
> objA: EF.Property(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType:
> TblDepartment ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
> Inner IsNullable: True , "DepartmentCode"), objB:
> EF.Property(t3, "DepartmentCode"))) .Where(t3 =>
> t3.ProgramCode.Equals(ca.ProgramCode))' could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At the very least you might tell us exactly what those errors are.

Comment: If you could post the error , that would be easy to help you

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3gyw1 @Darshani please review my errors

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the error *as text*. Essential parts of a question should be included in the question itself. Also, it usually helps to include the classes and mapping code (if present) as well, and the exact EF core version (I guess 5, because of the filtered Include).

Comment: Hi @MalikHamzaYounas, Can you share the related table definition, so that we could reproduce the problem more easier and help you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do includes with a where clause on it on EF Core 3.x as in this line:

```
.Include(ca => ca.Department.TblSemesters.Where(s => s.ProgramCode.Equals(ca.ProgramCode)))
```

You dont put the version of EF Core you are using, but i think this is the actual problem. This feature was added on EF Core 5 only. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include

Comment: This is not working as CourseAllocation is containing foreign key for Department then that is linked to tblsemesters and i want to condition from courseallocation table to tblsemesters

Comment: It is not working because ef core 3.x dont dupport Where on Include clauses.....